# can anyone explain get(0) in the statement content.get(0).preferred_UserName?

Tags: java

can anyone explain `get(0)` in the statement `content.get(0).preferred_UserName`?

I understand that `get(0)` is index but which value it is going to retrieve

```
public static String getUser(String userid)
        {
            String user=null;
            List<ContentPublisher> content = find("preferred_UserName = ?",userid).fetch();
            if(content.isEmpty())
            {
                user = "Guest";
            }
            else
            {
               user = content.get(0).preferred_UserName;

            }
            return user;
        }
```

This is my code and preferred_UserName is a variable in model class. I understand that `get(0)` is index but which value it is going to retrieve

Comment: assuming `content` is a List, `content.get(0)` will return the first element in that List.

Comment: Can you post the full code snippet? Is content of type `List`, and how is it populated? Normally get(0) returns the item that is added first.

Comment: Don't squish code into a comment. If someone is requesting clarification, add it into part of the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`get(0)` gets the very first element from the list, if specific order is required, there are ways to sort the list before doing `get(x)` operation.
Also check:

`Collections.sort()`

`Comparable interface`

Answer (score 1):

`user = content.get(0).preferred_UserName` would do the following:

- From content list, it will get the very first element it found from your `find` method
- It will assign preferred_UserName to user variable.